# use exec to run a process in the background and still write the output to a log file

Tags: php, shell, command-line, ssh

I have the following line in one of my php scripts that I run manually:

`exec("/usr/bin/php ".__DIR__."/driver.php > /dev/null &");`

How can I modify this so the output is written in a log file as well (in addition to running in the background). Below didn't work for me:

`exec("/usr/bin/php ".__DIR__."/driver1.php /tmp/log.txt > /dev/null &");`

Answer (score 3):

In bash/shell, the `>` operator tells it where to write the output. In your original command, the output is being sent to `/dev/null`, which means that it was being discarded. Instead, update the command to point to your log file:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php ".__DIR__."/driver1.php > /tmp/log.txt &");
```

If you want to *append* the content to that file, however (i.e. don't replace it every time that command is run) you will need to use `>>`:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php ".__DIR__."/driver1.php >> /tmp/log.txt &");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think `exec("/usr/bin/php ".__DIR__."/driver.php >> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1");`.

the > /dev/null in your original is what sends your output, but not to a log file. It goes to /dev/null.

the >> /tmp/log.txt should append your output to log.txt.

the 2>&1 should also redirect error output to this log file.